# How can I get my div the same height as my previous div sibling

Tags: html, css, height, percentage, siblings

I would like to have my one div have the same height as my previous div. I'm using percentages for widths and heights (so it looks better on a mobile device also. I've tried setting the parent elements to width and height of 100% also (saw that in a few forum posts, but it didn't work). I've also tried using display: table-cell, and that also didn't work. This is how my set up looks:

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
        <title>SiteTitle</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "styles/index.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "allContent">
            <div id = "header">
                <div id = "siteLogo">
                    <h1 id = "title">Site_Title</h1>
                </div>
                <div id = "shortMenu">
                    <a href = "#">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.css:

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: rgb(192, 74, 0);
}

div#allContent {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

div#allContent div#header {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div#allContent div#header div#siteLogo {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
}

div#allContent div#header div#siteLogo h1#title {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 300%;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

div#allContent div#header div#shortMenu {
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
}

div#allContent div#header div#shortMenu a {
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Not sure what to check now..
I basically want the bottom of the `Login` link to line up with the bottom of the website title. I'll probably change it to a logo image later, so the height may change, and I don't want to have to change the values if I decide to change it multiple times down the road. Right now the `Login` link is at the top of the page.

EDIT: I added the following lines of code, but it gave each div a width of 50%

```
div#allContent div#header {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

div#allContent div#header div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

using `display:table-cell`

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: rgb(192, 74, 0);
}

div#allContent {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

div#allContent div#header {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


div#allContent div#header div#siteLogo h1#title {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 300%;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
}


div#allContent div#header div#shortMenu a {
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    text-decoration: none;
}
div#allContent div#header div#shortMenu {
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div#allContent div#header div#siteLogo {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: table-cell;
}
div#allContent div#header {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<div id = "allContent">
            <div id = "header">
                <div id = "siteLogo">
                    <h1 id = "title">Site_Title</h1>
                </div>
                <div id = "shortMenu">
                    <a href = "#">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

using `display:flex`

replace this css code

```
div#allContent div#header div {
  flex: 1 auto;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: rgb(192, 74, 0);
}

div#allContent {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

div#allContent div#header {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div#allContent div#header div#siteLogo {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
}

div#allContent div#header div#siteLogo h1#title {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 300%;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
}

div#allContent div#header div#shortMenu {
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
}

div#allContent div#header div#shortMenu a {
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    text-decoration: none;
}
div#allContent div#header {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

div#allContent div#header div {
  flex: 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id = "allContent">
            <div id = "header">
                <div id = "siteLogo">
                    <h1 id = "title">Site_Title</h1>
                </div>
                <div id = "shortMenu">
                    <a href = "#">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I figured out the flex style, but I like using the table cell better as I feel I have a little more control. Not sure what I was trying before but it works. I have to look over CSS again, it's been about 3 or 4 years haha.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following selector. Please notice that display: inline-block; is to prevent ie11 possible bugs. Also i did not included the vendor prefixed styles for brevity.

```
div#allContent div#header div {
  flex: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```